# How do I fix the error 1120: Access of undefined property?

Tags: actionscript-3

While sitting, watching and reading about framework, I tried it and cant get my program going.

So when I programmed I had 3 frames. One for pre loader, one for Game (no menu, just straight to game), and one last one for me to keep notes and patch note etc in.
I coded in the frame. I didnt have any extra .as files or nothing, and it all works.

Then I tried converting to having a GameControler.as and a C.as (for constant values etc), and that didn't work.

So I started over, and ended up just trying it out and ended with this code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.ui.*;

    import Game.*;

    public class GameController extends MovieClip {


        private var score: Number;

        public function GameController() {
            // constructor code

        }

        public function startGame() {
            score = C.score;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }
        public function scoreF(e: MouseEvent):void {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        hitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scoreF)


        private function update(e: Event) {
            score_n.text = String(score);
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with these two errors.

```
Line 30, Column 3   1120: Access of undefined property hitBtn.
Line 30, Column 45  1120: Access of undefined property scoreF.
```

What am I not understanding?

I just wanna click the button, witch is on stage, add up the score and update the on stage score.

Comment: In a class you cannot run a code outside of class methods. Thta line: hitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scoreF) is not in any method so it has no scope to run the code your are trying to run. Put it in your constructor instead.

Comment: Thanx, got it to work. Dont know how, or why. But works. Back to reading more and watching more Tuts etc... Thanx. :D

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question was answered, here is a pattern you might want to follow:

```
package {
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.events.*;
  import flash.geom.*;
  import flash.text.*;
  import flash.utils.*;
  import flash.ui.*;

  import Game.*;

  public class GameController extends MovieClip {

    private var hitBtn:MovieClip;

    private var score: Number;

    public function GameController() {
        // constructor code
        createChildren();
    }

    protected function createChildren():void {
      // when it was not read from the display list
      // or created in a subclass via inheritence
      if (!hitBtn) {
        hitBtn = getChildByName('hitBtn') as MovieClip;
        if (hitBtn) {
          hitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scoreF);
        } else {
          trace('Child #hitBtn is not found or not a MovieClip.').
        }
      }
    }

    public function startGame() {
      score = C.score;
      if (stage) {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
      } else {
        trace("Attempt to start the game, although the controller is not added to stage.");
      }
    }

    public function scoreF(e: MouseEvent):void {
      score = score + 1;
    }

    private function update(e: Event) {
      score_n.text = String(score);
    }
  }
}
```

When using Flash to add children, those are added to the MovieClip when it is created, so you can access them right away. Following the pattern will give you more safety when working on larger projects, which sometimes change ... this way you can get very fast an idea of what's wrong.